# Angular 2 basic app not working

Tags: angular, npm-start

I am a newbie to Angular2. I was trying to setup Angular 2 using this reference: https://github.com/angular/quickstart. But unfortunately, I am unable to run my basic application.
I have installed npm. While running "npm start", I am getting below output in my command prompt:

```
`E:\Extrawork\Angular>npm start
> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart E:\Extrawork\Angular
> npm run build
> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build E:\Extrawork\Angular
> tsc -p src/
> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start E:\Extrawork\Angular
> concurrently "npm run build:watch" "npm run serve"
[0]
[0] > angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build:watch E:\Extrawork\Angular
[0] > tsc -p src/ -w
[0]
[1]
[1] > angular-quickstart@1.0.0 serve E:\Extrawork\Angular
[1] > lite-server -c=bs-config.json
[1]
[1] ** browser-sync config **
[1] { injectChanges: false,
[1]   files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
[1]   watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
[1]   server:
[1]    { baseDir: 'src',
[1]      middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ],
[1]      routes: { '/node_modules': 'node_modules' } } }
[0] 4:59:12 PM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
`
```

It stops here. I did wait for 20-30 mins but it doesn't proceed.
Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong, Please?

Comment: try to run ng serve in the project folder and see what it gives you

Comment: Delete your node_modules folder and run `npm install` again.

Comment: Thank you guys for your response. I have deleted my node_module folder and install again but I didn't find any luck. I am getting below warnings while installing npm. 
**npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fseve
nts@1.1.1**
Do you think anything is wrong with the installiation?

Comment: @radtelbi : I am getting error while running ng serve command
`E:\Extrawork\Angular>ng serve
Cannot read property 'config' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null
    at Class.run (E:\Extrawork\Angular\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\serve.js:
22:63)
    at check_port_1.checkPort.then.port (E:\Extrawork\Angular\node_modules\@angu
lar\cli\commands\serve.js:103:26)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)`

Comment: @Mitul some people having the same problem as you are suggesting that it is an angular-cli problem try the following :
uninstall the angular cli :`npm uninstall -g angular-cli` 
reinstall it :`npm install -g angular-cli@webpack`
 creates your new project `ng new projectname`
 moves you into the newly created directory `cd projectname` then `ng serve`

Comment: @radtelbi watch out, it's `@angular/cli` now. Make sure you install Angular-CLI correctly [read this tutorial](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#installation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use [Angular Cli](https://cli.angular.io/) this will generate files for you and add new files to necessary files like

> module.ts

for you as well
Plus it has commands that can analyse your code and point out possible error that may occur if you ran it and suggest the changes

Comment: Thank you guys, I don't understand what was wrong but I have reinstalled my node and npm as well as followed Angular-Cli steps mentioned on above link and it worked !

Answer (score 0):

This is freaking me out, guys!
I did setup it again to integrate with node to built a basic MEAN app and it gave me the same error again.That is insane!!!
Luckily, I was checking on youtube to setup and I found the same error with this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWsrJ2T6GFM. But the app was still able to execute. I thought of trying and it worked for me too!!
If it happens to you then I would suggest you to try to execute once even if it gives you a warning. It may work.